# Unintended recording from microphone in Pulseaudio

Tags: 18.04, sound, pulseaudio

I use regular earphones with built-in microphone for which I have created a female-to-2male wire which works fine(the earphones are plugged in and on the exit audio and microphone channels are separated). The only issue I have is that all the sound that I can hear is transmitted through the microphone like system sounds, music from Google Chrome, in-game sounds, etc. So I wanted to ask if anyone had the same issue or could help me solve it.

I use Ubuntu 18.04 and the earphone are plugged in from the rear panel.

Thanks.

p.s. link to Pulseaudio configuration images: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1vbiTvFnHMOXyYPEpypW1ER8_LuDhmVJM.

Comment: I guess there is something wrong with the separation of the channels in your homemade splitter. Please tell us how it is wired exactly.

Comment: I tested the wire on my friends pc and it worked well and also sometimes the issue won't show up for some period of time. I'll post the pictures of Pulseaudio configuration in 10 minutes.

Comment: When I use an application that requires microphone, like Discord, in the recording tab there shows up some "WEBRTC VoiceEngine" which I just added to the images. Thank you for your response!

Comment: By the way I forgot to mention that my friends pc is Windows powered and when I used Windows myself I didn't have this problem.